# Check hall avaiblity by date range in mysql where condition

Tags: mysql

My problem is that i want to count of id's between two dates range. But my written query is not give me required answer. sample is below .

```
select COUNT(hall_id) as countids 
from comm_hall_form 
where hall_id ='13' and ((date(booked_from)
between '2019-11-08' and '2019-11-09') or (date(booked_to) 
between '2019-11-08' and '2019-11-09'))
```

Comment: If hall_id can be duplicate then this query will not give you correct result.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the booked time fully or partially covers the period you are asking for. Right now you are only checking if it starts or ends with that period.

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) as countids 
 FROM comm_hall_form 
 WHERE hall_id ='13' 
 (DATE(booked_from) <= '2019-11-09' AND DATE(booked_to) >= '2019-11-09')
 OR
 (DATE(booked_from) <= '2019-11-08' AND DATE(booked_to) >= '2019-11-08')
```

Comment: your query is not working.
I explain -: suppose hall_id 13 is booked from 2019-11-07 to 2019-11-22. 

select COUNT(hall_id) as countids 
from comm_hall_form 
where hall_id ='13' and ((date(booked_from)
between '2019-11-08' and '2019-11-09') or (date(booked_to) 
between '2019-11-08' and '2019-11-09'))

This is my query to find booked hall from 08 to 09 it is return 0 count.
It should be return count of ids because 08,09 is range of 07 to 22.

Comment: @dikendrasoni You should have described this when you first wrote your question but now it is quite simple, I update my answer